# PHP handle "Failed opening ... for inclusion" error

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that triggers some "Failed opening ... for inclusion" fatal errors while using an external library.

Those errors are completely irrelevant and I would like to be able to handle them (doing basically nothing about those) to avoid errors to be raised.

How can I achieve that in PHP?

Thanks,
DaN

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php... although you should really get rid of those instead of suppressing them

Comment: you cannot handle fatal errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely want to hide the errors you can take a look at [PHP's Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). There's usually a reason for errors and/or warnings so it might be better to figure out what's causing these instead of just masking them.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress errors from individual statements by preceding it with the `@` operator.  For instance:

`@require_once('somefile.php');`